# Matplotlib: contour plot line style with markers

Tags: matplotlib, contour, linestyle

Is there a way to make a contour plot `ax.contour` line style not a simply dot-dashed but with some hollow markers, like this:

[image]

In [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) I see only `linestyles` parameter with limited set of values, and I know also about a way to tune dash-dot style, like this                 `linestyles=[(0, (7, 3))]`, but what I looking for is a way to use a marker instead of a simple point in dot-dash style.

Comment: Does this [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) help?

Comment: @JacobK, no, it didn’t help. I have updated the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have the line type you want. I referred to [this page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html).